# How can I pass a data element that has been bound on one HTML file to another HTML file in an AngularJS app

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding

I am using this statement in the Index.html file to bind the element: Show Products.

I see that is is bound in the Index fie by displaying its value there. But when the products1.html file opens, the bound field does not display. I want to use it in as a placeholder in an input box in products1.html.

I am thinking of re-creating index.html as an SPA, but not sure this will work.  if I add products1.html as a template into the view. I expect I might have the same problem.

Yes I am a Angularjs newbie after 2 years of experience.

Comment: this is the statement that binds the data <a ng-click="selectRow(user)" ng-href={{"products1.html"}}>Show Products

Comment: Could you please, share your controller(s) code?

Comment: Here is first controller that SelectsRow

Comment: Thanks for the reply Javier, but it is too long to cut and paste here. The controller for the first page works fine. I do not reference the data element, {{selectedRow.methodNumber}}, in my second controller, only on the HTML of the second page that is called. But it will not display there, but does display on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have different controllers for the two pages, it seems that your problem is that you are not sharing the data between those controllers. Each of the controllers define a scope. It looks like the information that you want to show is well loaded in the "Index.html" controller scope, but then is not passed to the "products1.html" controller. If that is the case, there is several solutions to share data between Angular controllers:

1. Using services
2. Using $state.go services
3. Using stateparams
4. using rootscope

You can check how to do it in: [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)